# Using number pipe throws InvalidPipeArgumentException (Invalid argument '1' for pipe 'DecimalPipe')

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-pipe

I want to write some number into `<input>` and dynamically display it as a decimal inside `{{}}` through pipe. It throws exception instead. Here's my code:

app.template.html:

```
<h1>amount = {{amount|number:'1.2-2'}}</h1>
<input [(ngModel)]="amount"/>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.template.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  private amount:number;
}
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/I7ynnwBX4DWJfHNPIPRu?p=preview

Write any number into the input and see exception being thrown in the console.

---

**Edit:**

Working code as per rinukkusu suggestion:

app.template.html:

```
<h1>amount = {{amount|number:'1.2-2'}}</h1>
<input [ngModel]="amount" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"/>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.template.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  private amount:number;

  onChange($event) {
    this.amount = +$event;
  }
}
```

This `+` next to `$event` is very important and what makes conversion from string to number possible!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looking at the source code of Angular 2 I found this:

```ts
if (!isNumber(value)) {
  throw new InvalidPipeArgumentException(pipe, value);
}
```

which means, you actually need to pass a variable of type number. Using the `input` and binding to `ngModel` like you did there, your `amount` variable will always be of type string.

> Remember: type hints are only visible in TypeScript. After transpiling
>   to JavaScript you lose that information

I'd suggest implementing a new pipe which converts your variable to a number on the fly:

```ts
@Pipe({
    name: 'toNumber'
})
export class ToNumberPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string):any {
        let retNumber = Number(value);
        return isNaN(retNumber) ? 0 : retNumber;
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```ts
<h1>amount = {{amount | toNumber | number:'1.2-2'}}</h1>
<input [(ngModel)]="amount" />
```

Comment: Have you tried it? AFAIR `+xxx` (unary plus) doesn't work in templates, only in code.

Comment: Actually no - I assumed them to work haha. I will try and edit my answer, if they don't work!

Comment: Okay, so it doesn't work, like @GünterZöchbauer said. I updated my answer with a new approach, which fits better than mangling with the bound variable, because if you change the bound variable on change, the input also changes, which is confusing for the user.

Answer (score -1):

Following rinukkusu's solution above -- I was able to do it without creating a custompipe. I just used `<input [(ngModel)]="Number(amount)|number:'1.2-2'"/>` and it worked for me.

Comment: I'm using angular 6 and tried this but got .Number is not a function

Comment: @goneos, you can make `Number` accessible to the template by setting a property in the ts like `Number = Number`